# SQL Bulk copy when doing write to server throws exception

Tags: sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to do bulk copy using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer. It gives me an exception. Cannot create a row of size 8635 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
The statement has been terminated. Can someone please explain me what this is ?

Comment: As specified in the MSDN documentation, 8,060 bytes is the maximum size allowed per row. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx]

Comment: So is there no way to overcome this limitation. I have a scneario where in I need to store around 1000 columns, each column can have max length

Comment: It basically depends from the data types used in your table, but you can try enabling the large value types out of row option in SQLServer [ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087.aspx ]. BTW, if you need 1000 columns in a table, I would seriously reconsider your design